# Using a script that uses Duplicity + S3 excluding large files

Tags: backup, bash, script, amazon-s3, duplicity

I'm trying to write an backup script that will exclude files over a certain size.

If i run the script duplicity gives an error. However if I copy and paste the same command generated by the script everything works...

Here is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Export some ENV variables so you don't have to type anything
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="accesskey"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="secretaccesskey"
export PASSPHRASE="password"

SOURCE=/home/
DEST=s3+http://s3bucket

GPG_KEY="gpgkey"

# exclude files over 100MB
exclude ()
{
 find /home/jason -size +100M \
 | while read FILE; do 
  echo -n " --exclude "
  echo -n \'**${FILE##/*/}\' | sed 's/\ /\\ /g' #Replace whitespace with "\ "
 done
}

echo "Using Command"
echo "duplicity --encrypt-key=$GPG_KEY --sign-key=$GPG_KEY `exclude` $SOURCE $DEST"

duplicity --encrypt-key=$GPG_KEY --sign-key=$GPG_KEY `exclude` $SOURCE $DEST

# Reset the ENV variables.
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
export PASSPHRASE=
```

When the script is run I get  the error;

```
Command line error: Expected 2 args, got 6
```

Where am i going wrong??

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem..

```
#!/bin/bash
# Export some ENV variables so you don't have to type anything
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="accesskey"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="secretaccesskey"
export PASSPHRASE="password"

SOURCE=/home/
DEST=s3+http://s3bucket

GPG_KEY="gpgkey"

# Generate a filelist of excluded files over 100MB
find $SOURCE -size +100M > /tmp/filelist

duplicity --exclude-filelist /tmp/filelist --encrypt-key=$GPG_KEY --sign-key=$GPG_KEY $SOURCE $DEST

# Reset the ENV variables.
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
export PASSPHRASE=
```